# indentation in python code uses four instead of one tab, sometimes

Tags: python

Finishing up the code and it's all good and even working, it's just that in the python script, some loops use 4 tabs (!) as one indentation, others the usual 1 tab. I can't figure out what's the problem ? (in the code, the only difference is that some loops are thus much further extended to the right, given that for each loop, four tabs are placed before the first character of a new line, each time a line is finished with a return).

Example :

Normal:

```
for x in range(5):
      print (x)
```

But sometimes:

```
for x in range(5):
                                        print(x)
```

The difference in between these two examples is sth that is not done by myself; on both loops, all I do is press the return key after the semicolon. Nothing changes, even if I delete the print part and rewrite it with a new return key hit after going back to the semicolon.

Comment: Can you include an example? I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: Sounds infuriating. Guessing this is an editor problem rather than a python problem tho. More info required.

Comment: You shouldn't be using tabs in your Python code. Trying to mix tabs and spaces for indentation is a recipe for unhappiness and disaster.

Comment: This sounds like an editor problem, not a python problem. Can you mention which editor you're using?

Comment: larsks are you using tabs as indentation? the thing is that I never did any indentation actually, it automatically jumped to the right by one tab if I press the return key after a semicolon in my code....

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso: Or they're using a non-standard REPL (like `ipython` or the like, but presumably weirder, since I've never seen `ipython` do this) entering code line-by-line, but we'd still need to know the REPL they're using.

Comment: @ CoffeeTable not sure if you mean the IDLE version ? (3.6.4 in my case). Otherwise, what do you mean by editor, sorry..?

Comment: @Joe what are you using to write your python code?

Comment: @Joe IDE is short for Integrated Development Environment. It's basically a text editor with a bunch of extra features to make it easier to write code. (stuff like running your code from the IDE for example, or jumping to where a function is defined.)

Comment: @ShadowRanger you're right, I just assumed they were using a text editor. could be a REPL too

Comment: Yeah I'm using IDLE 3.6.4. But oh man forget it folks, I found it, it's because I forgot one bracket about 400 lines higher in the code. Weirdly the code didn't get any error message when I executed it, so not sure if that's really the reason.... (at least the indentation became normal again once I put the missing bracket in, but now I can enjoy redoing all these wrong tabs again....) Sorry for bothering guys, was looking for a solution for a long time and just got it now.... -.-

Comment: set up you IDE to make 4 spaces with one press of a tab because it is recommended by PEP8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces

Comment: @ŠarūnasAžna cheers man!